# Задержка при следующим each

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы переходил к следующей форме через 2 секунды?

пробовал так, но что-то не так

```
   $(this).closest('.product-item').find('form.ms2_form').each(function(i){
        if ($(this).find('input[name="count"]').val() > 0) { 
            //$(this).submit();
            $(this).find('.msmcd-action').delay(5000 * (i + 1)).click();
              //$(this).find('.msmcd-action').trigger('click');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.product-item .cart-btn').click(function(){
            $(this).closest('.product-item').find('form.ms2_form').each(function(i, elem){
                 setTimeout(function(){
                    if ($(elem).find('input[name="count"]').val() > 0) { 
                        //$(this).submit();
                        $(elem).find('.msmcd-action').click();
                          //$(this).find('.msmcd-action').trigger('click');
                    }
                }, 1000 * i);

            });
        });
```